# Can't Boot to Live CD - Samsung NP355E5C-A01US

Tags: boot, 14.04

I am trying to upgrade my laptop, a Samsung NP355E5C-A01US, from Ubuntu 12.10 to 14.04.

The previous installation (Ubuntu 12.10) has become a bit unstable making this very difficult.

I have a Live CD with the new OS loaded onto it and when I run the disk with it tells me to reboot from the CD.

[image]

When I reboot I don't see any options to boot to the Live CD.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you see the normal grub boot loader, not the one from the CD. You most probably have to change the bootorder in your BIOS to change the boot priority.

Maybe this helps, depending on your model:
[Change boot order (Samsung)](https://superuser.com/questions/521389/how-do-i-boot-my-samsung-laptop-from-a-cd-dvd)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! So would you have any idea which option I would want to set to boot first? Here is a screenshot of what I have availible to me. (Screenshot: http://i46.photobucket.com/albums/f146/Happy_Little_Clouds/IMAG0537_zpsef0c9d5e.jpg).

Comment: Yes, the 4th option you see "TSSTcorp CDDVD...." and please dont forget to set the second boot prio then to your harddrive which is curretnly active on selection 1